# cancel running GitHub action on branch deletion workflow

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm trying to cancel a running workflow using another one that triggers on branch deletion.
for that, I found some actions that don't work for me since none of them refer to "on: delete".
I also tried concurrency:

```
concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true
```

or

```
concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.event.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true
```

but since the branch no longer exists it doesn't work and it uses the "default" branch.
any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Please describe what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I have a workflow that deploys on push no matter what the branch name is. and another workflow that deletes any resource according to the branch name. in some cases I want to push without "deploy", and want to cancel any running workflows using another workflow that triggered "on: delete" before the 1st workflow will create the resources. sometimes, the branch is deleted before the resources were created. I hope this describes my problem better.